# How to get tests to record fixtures with AngularJs like vcr in Rails?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, vcr

I've been looking everywhere, I tried node-replay but with protractor but it won't work with selenium.

I've also tried vcr.js and sepia.

How do I go about setting up my tests for that they make the initial calls but store them as cassettes like vcr.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you found something? This would be helpful to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: up to now i'm using angular-mock but it involves pasting responses from the inspector. it's not as slick as i'd like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been setting up sepia to be used with protractor.
It works now, here is what I did:

I assume you've already set up grunt-connect to run your protractor tests.

Then you'll need to wait for the event listening event from the connect configuration:
`grunt.event.once('connect.test.listening', function)`

And that's where you will configure sepia.

```
  grunt.event.once('connect.test.listening', function(host, port) {
    /**
     * Configure sepia here
     */

    var sepia = require('sepia').withSepiaServer();

    // Use your custom configuration
    sepia.configure({
      verbose: true,
      debug: true,
      includeHeaderNames: false,
      includeCookieNames: false
    });

    // I have some path/body content to filter configured in the vrc configuration
    var bodyFilters = grunt.config('vcr.filters.body') || [];
    var pathFilters = grunt.config('vcr.filters.path') || [];
    var regexPath = function(string) {
      var escapedString = string.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
      return new RegExp(escapedString);
    };

    // Filter path
    _.map(pathFilters, function(filter) {
      sepia.filter({
        url: regexPath(filter.path),
        urlFilter: function(url) {
          return url.replace(filter.pattern, filter.replacement);
        }
      });
    });

    // Filter body content
    _.map(bodyFilters, function(filter) {
      sepia.filter({
        url: regexPath(filter.path),
        bodyFilter: function(body) {
          return body.replace(filter.pattern, filter.replacement);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```